# Can i Post Image and Text in facebook Without open any Dialog box or Browser in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I have created an Application To Post Image and Text Both on `Facebook` but my Client Requirement is to Post image and Text Without Opening any Dialog Box and safari Browser.

Can i Post Image and Text using `Facebook` User ID without opening any dialog  Box or Safari?

I have Tried :

1) **SLComposeViewController** But it will open share Dialog First.

2) **FBSDKShareDialog** but it will goes to Safari Browser.

I Need To Post Image and Text on `Facebook` in Background.

Comment: No, now it's not possible :( but few years ago it was possible and we do a lot.

Comment: You are not allowed to publish a text that the user did not enter themself - so trying to do this “in the background” would only make sense if you have another way for the user to input the text they want posted with the photo. Your app is not allowed to specify the text for them. (If that’s what your client wants, then tell them to go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) please.) That being said, background would mean using the API, not the dialogs.

Comment: as per my understanding, without click on **POST** button you can not post anything in the Facebook. Facebook is third party app and you don't have any permissions to access their methods which is private. Especially iPhone is giving security and privacy for users. Without user knowing and their interaction, nothing will work I hope so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO.** You can't do that. Apple will not allow you to poke into social life of user without their permission. It will surely show a dialogue and user have to tap on post then only post will be shown on FB.

Comment: Thank you For you answer @pushkraj.i have one more question can i post on Twitter in Background?

Comment: Actually it depends upon SDK provided by each social networking sites. And in almost every SDK, popup will be shown or permission will be taken from user before posting anything on respective sites.

Comment: Thanks for the help.